# Display search results on keypress

Tags: reactjs

I am tryng to display search results for each key press on my input:

```
getMovies(e){ 
    axios.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${e.target.value}`)
   .then((response) => {
    this.setState({ movies: response.data });
    })
.catch((error) => {
     console.log(error);
   });
}

render() {
   return (
      <div className="container">
        <SearchForm onkeydown={this.getMovies}  />
        <MovieList movies={this.state.movies}/>
     </div>
     );
   }
}
```

In my search form I bind my function to the FormControl `onChange`:

```
 export default class SearchForm extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <Row>
           <Col md={6} >
            <h2>Custom search field</h2>
               <div className="custom-search-input">
                   <Col md={12} className="input-group" >
                          <FormControl
                            type="text"
                            bsSize="lg"
                            value={this.props.val}
                            placeholder="Enter text"
                            onChange={this.props.onkeydown.bind(this)}
                        />
                    <span className="input-group-btn">
                        <button className="btn btn-lg" type="button">
                            <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </Col>
            </div>
        </Col>
  </Row>)
    }
 }
```

My movielist component:

```
export default class MovieList extends React.Component{

render(){
var userNodes = this.props.movies.map(function(movie){
    return (
          <tr key={movie.id}>
            <td>{movie.Year}</td>
            <td >{movie.Title}</td>
            <td >{movie.Released}</td>   
          </tr>
        )
    });

    return (
      <div>
       <Table responsive>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Released</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {userNodes}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
      </div>
    );
```

}
}

I can get the response on the network panel, but the state is not updating to display the `MovieList` component.

How can I update the `state` and display it in my `MovieList` ?

Comment: are you getting data in console.log(response.data)

Comment: i think you need to change:  <SearchForm onkeydown={this.getUsers.bind(this)}/> or You have not used componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) inside MovieList  component to receive updated props.

Comment: Can you show us how you render the `movies` in `MovieList` component?

Comment: Edited original post, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked that API and seems it returns an `object`, not an `array`.

#### Update 1

You can convert your component in something like:

```
export default class MovieList extends React.Component{

  render(){
      const { movie } = this.props;
      return (
        <div>
         <Table responsive>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Id</th>
                  <th>Year</th>
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Released</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>{movie.imdbID}</td>
                  <td>{movie.Year}</td>
                  <td>{movie.Title}</td>
                  <td>{movie.Released}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
      );
  }
  
}
```

and use it like:

```
<MovieList movie={this.state.movies} />
```

### Please notice I'm using `movie` instead of `movies`.

#### Update 2:

You can also (and I would suggest doing this) convert your MovieList into a [dumb functional component](https://medium.com/@joshblack/stateless-components-in-react-0-14-f9798f8b992d):

```
const MovieList = ({ movie }) => (
  <div>
    <Table responsive>
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>Id</th>
             <th>Year</th>
             <th>Title</th>
             <th>Released</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td>{movie.imdbID}</td>
             <td>{movie.Year}</td>
             <td>{movie.Title}</td>
             <td>{movie.Released}</td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
       </Table>
  </div>
)

export default MovieList;
```

Comment: Thanks, how can i get object into the child component `onkeypress`?

Comment: Thanks! Its the props in the list component that don't show. I can only get the table to show on first render, it doesnt refresh with the state change.